# AngularJS $resource with API supplying root key

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am building an Angular app that communicates with a server that supplies resources wrapped in a root key.

In other words, a request to `GET /api/posts` gives the JSON response `{ posts: [ ... ] }`.

Similarly, single resource requests are also contained in a root key, such that `GET /api/post/1` returns something along the lines of `{ post: {title: "Title"} }`.

I would like to use `$resource` to handle fetching these resources, and have set up a factory with the typical line:

`$resource('/api/posts/:id', {id: '@id'})`

But naturally this won't work as it does not expect to have to look for a root key, and expects an array instead of an object when querying, etc.

I'm wondering if there's a relatively easy way to make this transparent for `$resource` so that it can be used as normal. I've tried searching around for a solution but couldn't find anything related to this specific case. It's totally possible I'm missing something painfully obvious in the `$resource` documentation, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If your web API is returning a single item, you can create your own query-method for resource that simply overwrites isArray: false. Have you tried that?

Comment: Good call...I was thinking about this the wrong way. I can just overwrite isArray and then return the value of the key to whatever needs it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was easier than I thought.  As suggested by [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116249/patrick) in his comment, it's merely a matter of overwriting the `query` method to have `isArray: false`, and then plucking the key out manually.  In practice, it looks something like this:

```
$resource('/api/posts/:id', {id: '@id'}, {query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}})

...

$resource.query({}, function(response) {
    posts = response.posts;
    // Do whatever with posts
})
```

I had been wondering if there was a way to actually have `$resource.query()` return only the value of the root key, but this doesn't make sense and is unnecessary.

Comment: The response.posts will not be an instance of ngResource though so can't use instance methods like $save?